Flutter ImagePicker Not able to run or build project when I add it to pubspec.yaml
When I add the Image picker library to my project it start giving following issue when ever I try to build/run the project.
My pubspec.yaml file
name: splitwise_flutter
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: 0.8.6
  get: ^4.6.6
  google_fonts: ^6.2.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.2.0+3
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.4
  flutter_otp_text_field: ^1.1.3+2
  firebase_core: ^3.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^5.2.1
  firebase_storage: ^12.1.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/2x/
    - assets/images/3x/
    - assets/images/4x/

  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400

  uses-material-design: true

Flutter Doctor Summary :
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4780], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Error:
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:11:27: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
SourceType _convertSource(ImageSource source) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:28:29: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
SourceCamera _convertCamera(CameraDevice camera) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:45:30: Error: Type 'ImagePickerPlatform' not found.
class ImagePickerIOS extends ImagePickerPlatform {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:54:10: Error: Type 'PickedFile' not found.
  Future<PickedFile?> pickImage({
         ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:55:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:59:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:75:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:76:5: Error: Type 'ImagePickerOptions' not found.
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:86:15: Error: Type 'PickedFile' not found.
  Future<List<PickedFile>?> pickMultiImage({
              ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:111:5: Error: Type 'MultiImagePickerOptions' not found.
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:118:5: Error: Type 'MultiImagePickerOptions' not found.
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:153:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:154:5: Error: Type 'ImagePickerOptions' not found.
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:185:14: Error: Type 'MediaOptions' not found.
    required MediaOptions options,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:195:48: Error: Type 'ImageOptions' not found.
  MaxSize _imageOptionsToMaxSizeWithValidation(ImageOptions imageOptions) {
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:217:7: Error: Type 'MediaOptions' not found.
      MediaOptions mediaOptions) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:246:10: Error: Type 'PickedFile' not found.
  Future<PickedFile?> pickVideo({
         ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:247:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:248:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:260:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:261:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:273:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:277:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:317:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:318:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:59:42: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:76:40: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'ImagePickerOptions'.
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:111:45: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'MultiImagePickerOptions'.
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:118:45: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'MultiImagePickerOptions'.
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:154:40: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'ImagePickerOptions'.
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:248:42: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:261:42: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:277:42: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:318:42: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:11:27: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
SourceType _convertSource(ImageSource source) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:13:10: Error: Undefined name 'ImageSource'.
    case ImageSource.camera:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:15:10: Error: Undefined name 'ImageSource'.
    case ImageSource.gallery:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:28:29: Error: 'CameraDevice' isn't a type.
SourceCamera _convertCamera(CameraDevice camera) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:30:10: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    case CameraDevice.front:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:32:10: Error: Undefined name 'CameraDevice'.
    case CameraDevice.rear:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:50:5: Error: Undefined name 'ImagePickerPlatform'.
    ImagePickerPlatform.instance = ImagePickerIOS();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:55:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:59:5: Error: 'CameraDevice' isn't a type.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:63:16: Error: The method 'ImagePickerOptions' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ImagePickerOptions'.
      options: ImagePickerOptions(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:70:27: Error: The method 'PickedFile' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'PickedFile'.
    return path != null ? PickedFile(path) : null;
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:75:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:76:5: Error: 'ImagePickerOptions' isn't a type.
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:92:16: Error: The method 'MultiImagePickerOptions' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MultiImagePickerOptions'.
      options: MultiImagePickerOptions(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:93:23: Error: The method 'ImageOptions' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ImageOptions'.
        imageOptions: ImageOptions(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:106:40: Error: The method 'PickedFile' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'PickedFile'.
    return paths.map((dynamic path) => PickedFile(path as String)).toList();
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:111:5: Error: 'MultiImagePickerOptions' isn't a type.
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:118:5: Error: 'MultiImagePickerOptions' isn't a type.
    MultiImagePickerOptions options = const MultiImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:153:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:154:5: Error: 'ImagePickerOptions' isn't a type.
    ImagePickerOptions options = const ImagePickerOptions(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:185:14: Error: 'MediaOptions' isn't a type.
    required MediaOptions options,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:195:48: Error: 'ImageOptions' isn't a type.
  MaxSize _imageOptionsToMaxSizeWithValidation(ImageOptions imageOptions) {
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:217:7: Error: 'MediaOptions' isn't a type.
      MediaOptions mediaOptions) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:247:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:248:5: Error: 'CameraDevice' isn't a type.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:256:27: Error: The method 'PickedFile' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'PickedFile'.
    return path != null ? PickedFile(path) : null;
                          ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:260:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:261:5: Error: 'CameraDevice' isn't a type.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:273:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:277:5: Error: 'CameraDevice' isn't a type.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:281:16: Error: The method 'ImagePickerOptions' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ImagePickerOptions'.
      options: ImagePickerOptions(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:298:16: Error: The method 'MultiImagePickerOptions' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'MultiImagePickerOptions'.
      options: MultiImagePickerOptions(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:299:23: Error: The method 'ImageOptions' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerIOS'.
 - 'ImagePickerIOS' is from 'package:image_picker_ios/image_picker_ios.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ImageOptions'.
        imageOptions: ImageOptions(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:317:14: Error: 'ImageSource' isn't a type.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.12/lib/image_picker_ios.dart:318:5: Error: 'CameraDevice' isn't a type.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_platform_interface-2.10.0/lib/src/types/types.dart: Error: The control character U+0000 can only be used in strings and comments.
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_platform_interface-2.10.0/lib/src/platform_interface/image_picker_platform.dart: Error: The control character U+0000 can only be used in strings and comments.
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:13:34: Error: Type 'ImagePickerPlatform' not found.
class ImagePickerAndroid extends ImagePickerPlatform {
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:31:10: Error: Type 'PickedFile' not found.
  Future<PickedFile?> pickImage({
         ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:32:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:36:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:49:15: Error: Type 'PickedFile' not found.
  Future<List<PickedFile>?> pickMultiImage({
              ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:104:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:108:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:139:10: Error: Type 'PickedFile' not found.
  Future<PickedFile?> pickVideo({
         ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:140:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:141:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:153:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:154:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:170:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:174:5: Error: Type 'CameraDevice' not found.
    CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:188:14: Error: Type 'ImageSource' not found.
    required ImageSource source,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^

             ^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:328:12: Error: The method 'LostData' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerAndroid'.
 - 'ImagePickerAndroid' is from 'package:image_picker_android/image_picker_android.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LostData'.
    return LostData(
           ^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:329:35: Error: The method 'PickedFile' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerAndroid'.
 - 'ImagePickerAndroid' is from 'package:image_picker_android/image_picker_android.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'PickedFile'.
      file: result.file != null ? PickedFile(result.file!.path) : null,
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^

               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart:416:12: Error: The getter 'RetrieveType' isn't defined for the class 'ImagePickerAndroid'.
 - 'ImagePickerAndroid' is from 'package:image_picker_android/image_picker_android.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_android-0.8.12+12/lib/image_picker_android.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'RetrieveType'.
    return RetrieveType.image;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Kanwar\Documents\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.


You have mentioned invalid version of image_picker (0.8.6 does not exist), refer this for valid versions: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/versions

I guess you missing '^' before version of image_picker in pubspec.yaml file.
Give it like image_picker: ^0.8.6

Downloading packages...
image_picker 0.8.6 (1.1.2 available)
image_picker_for_web 2.2.0 (3.0.5 available)
Regard less of what version I am using I get the same error.

try using actually the latest version (1.1.2)


Try using the latest version of imagePicker or
Try running flutter clean and then flutter pub cache clean then flutter pub get and try running the app again
Sometimes, Invalidating cache of android studio and restarting will also help


Already tried this, now going to downgrade flutter version

try : image_picker: ^1.1.2
